# How to open an .html or .css file in Brackets from the terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, adobe-brackets

I am using Brackets in Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu gets the following error when trying to open a file in Brackets from the terminal.

```
$ brackets developers.html 
[1007/002314:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[1007/002314:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)
[1007/002314:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
[1007/002314:ERROR:gconf_listener.cc(117)] Error with gconf key '/apps/metacity/general': Failed to activate configuration server: The name org.gnome.GConf was not provided by any .service files

[1007/002317:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)
[1007/002317:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] Gtk: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
```

I tried changing directories to the location of developers.html with `cd` and running `brackets developers.html` with sudo and without sudo, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets only supports opening files from the command line in Windows and Mac, not in Linux. According to [Brackets Command Line Tools](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments):

> Linux support is still in progress - Brackets can be launched from the command line, but it does not accept arguments.

Opening an html or css file in Brackets by selecting *File* -> *Open* -> browse to a file and select it -> click *Open* button works properly.

Opening files/folders in Brackets from the terminal in Brackets is a feature request at [Adobe Brackets Trello board](https://trello.com/c/6JZLKIHn/1379-open-file-folder-from-command-line-on-linux-or-set-as-default-app). Need to implement `GetPendingFilesToOpen()` in [appshell_extensions_gtk](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/release-1.2/appshell/appshell_extensions_gtk.cpp#L736-L738) to read files from command line arguments.